# tt_address: add categorys of address to the template

Tags: templates, typo3, typo3-4.5

Is it somehow possible to add the sub-group of a cetrain group the address is assigned to the html output?

In the template I have `###MAINGROUP###` and `###GROUPLIST###`. I can't use maingroup, cause it's not the case that the group I need is always the maingroup. And with the grouplist I can't say which group is the sub-group of the one group.

Anyone have an idea how I could do it?

And in addition to that I also need the value of a self created field in the tt_address table.

### Edit:

I try it like @lorenz say. What I have so far:

ext_localconf.php:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_address']['extraItemMarkerHook'][] 
='EXT:txnextaddresssort/class.tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers.php:tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers';
```

class.tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers.php:

```
<?php
class tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers {
    function extraItemMarkerProcessor(&$markerArray, &$address, &$lConf, 
        &$pObj) { 

        $lcObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj'); 
        $lcObj->data = $address; 

        $markerArray['###SORTBEREICH###']   = 
        $lcObj->stdWrap($address['tx_nextaddresssort_sort_bereich'], 
        $lConf['tx_nextaddresssort_sort_bereich.']); 

    } 

}
```

Extentionkey: next_address_sort

All I get is a blank screen, but no errors in apache log

Comment: Did you just add these files to a folder namend next_address_sort or did you really kickstart an extension (with all the necessary files, e.g. ext_emconf.php)? "EXT:txnextaddresssort" would try to open a folder called "txnextaddresssort", but your extension is namend "next_address_sort".

Comment: @lorenz It is a real extension, installed in the extensionmanager (it extends the tt_address with the db fields). I already changed "txnextaddresssort" to "nextaddresssort" and "next_address_sort". (Sometimes the extkey dont work with underscores). When I do it with "next_address_sort" I get an output, but NO markers - not even the original ones like ###ADDRESS### - will be replaced. Current code: http://pastebin.com/Fm0tPAH3

Comment: Ah, I forgot the obvious: "return $markerArray;" I just edited my answer.

Comment: @lorenz oh, the function have to return the array. You know what? Thank you very much! Not only it works now, I have also lerned something!

Comment: @lorenz Still have a little cache problem. When I change the value of my custom field via backend or direct in DB I still see the old value in the frontend until i clear the cache or call the page with `?no_cache=1`. The only way I found so far is to change the `ext_localconf.php` and set in frontentplugin (in addPItoST43) to nocache. Do you know a way without touching tt_address?

Comment: This is a general TYPO3 problem. The easiest way around is to set TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = all (or better TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = pageId,pageId,pageId where pageIds are the IDs of the pages containing a tt_address plugin) in the Page TS Configuration of the folder containing the addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no possibility to do that.

Yet you can write a custom extension that integrates the extraItemMarkerProcessorhook in tt_address. In ext_localconf.php, add:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_address']['extraItemMarkerHook'][]     ='EXT:myextension/class.tx_myextension_filename.php:tx_myextension_classname';
```

Then add a file class.tx_myextension_filename.php to your extension.:

```
class tx_myextension_classname {

    public function extraItemMarkerProcessor(&$markerArray, &$address, &$lConf, &$pObj) {

      $lcObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
      $lcObj->data = $address;

      $markerArray['###MYFIELD###'] = $lcObj->stdWrap($address['myfieldlikeindatabase'], $lConf['myfieldlikeindatabase.']);

      return $markerArray;

    }

}
```

This would be an example for getting a field that is in the tt_address table and adding it to the markers so they can be used in a template. It is also stdWrap enabled.

Now, instead of getting a field, you should replace $address['myfieldlikeindatabase'] with a variable that contains the information you need. To receive the data, you can use the TYPO3 database API functions ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']).

Comment: I think we just found the same source. I try it this way, but it's not working. I will edit my question to show what I have so far

Comment: Why I can't use $address['myfieldlikeindatabase'] (where myfieldlikeindatabase is the name of my field)? When I use the database API, i need the uid from the address is that saved in $address? currently I just get a blank screen on the page I include the tt_address plugin.

Comment: Blank screen means that you have a PHP parsing error. Check your log. The "same source" is a mailing list post by me (but in German :-)). I'm using this setup in several installations, so I know that it works...

Comment: ok, then I found your post :) I had the same idea about an error, but checked the apache error log and there was nothing. I will post now my  localconf and my class in the question.

Comment: Still works in TYPO3 7 LTS, but use `$lcObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class);` for `$lcObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');`