# TYPO3 How can I add own data (datafields) into tt_address?

Tags: typo3

I'm using TYPO3 v 6.2 and the Extension tt_address.
I need more (data)fields into the tt_address-table.

I've read, that I can add more db-fields via kickstarter.
So I installed TYPO3 4.5 and install kickstarter.

Add new Extension "ttaddressaddfields". Add the "tt_address"-DB-table at "Extend Existing Tables". Add a new Data-Field type String "email1".  View Result -> Write -> Install ext. and voila!
Everything works .. I have a new Field at my tt_address Form called "email1".
In the database, the field email1 was written with my content.

BUT! How can I show my result in Frontend? Do I have to edit the tt_address-Setup.ts?

I add this at my own Extension at ext_localconf.php

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_address']['extendingTCA'][] = 'ttaddressaddnew';
?>
```

in my HTML-template (from tt_address)

```
###PHONE###
<br>Extrafeld :&nbsp;    ###EMAIL1###
```

Anyhow .. it doesn't work! Where is my fault? I've no idea ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all! I've done it!

After create [a new Extension at Kickstarter](http://www.herzogkienast.de/benutzerregistrierung-erweitern.html) ...

In my Template for tt_address

```
###EMAIL1###
```

My Extra field in tt_address-table is called

```
tx_ttaddressextended_email1
```

Add a new class-file (class.tx_ttaddressextended_filename.php) in my new Extension typo3conf/ext/tt_address_extended/

```
<?php
class tx_ttaddressextended_classname {

    public function extraItemMarkerProcessor(&$markerArray, &$address, &$lConf, &$pObj) {

      $lcObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
      $lcObj->data = $address;

      $markerArray['###EMAIL1###'] = $lcObj->stdWrap($address['tx_ttaddressextended_email1'], $lConf['tx_ttaddressextended_email1']);

      return $markerArray;

    }

}
?>
```

And the HOOK at a new file ext_localconf.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_address']['extraItemMarkerHook'][] = 'EXT:tt_address_extended/class.tx_ttaddressextended_filename.php:tx_ttaddressextended_classname';

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to write your own hook for tt_address's extra itemmarker array.

Example taken from [tt-address-add-categorys-of-address-to-the-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569667/tt-address-add-categorys-of-address-to-the-template), but to make everybody happy include the essential parts here:

ext_localconf.php:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_address']['extraItemMarkerHook'][] 
='EXT:txnextaddresssort/class.tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers.php:tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers';
```

class.tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers.php:

```
    <?php
    class tx_next_address_sort_addmarkers {
      function extraItemMarkerProcessor(&$markerArray, &$address, &$lConf, 
        &$pObj) { 

        $lcObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj'); 
        $lcObj->data = $address; 

        $markerArray['###EMAIL1###']   = $address['email1'];
      } 
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @krumia, i didn't know that it's bad to help someone by just linking to another stackoverflow answer. So, i've included the codes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better you write your own extension and use tt_address db fields.
I do that every time, because when i need to extend it more, its no problem in my own extension.

Comment: I'm not a PHP-Pro, so I've Problems to write my own extension. I found some tutorials to extend a popular TYPO3-Extension, but it doesn't work ..?!

Comment: Uh... But it´s not verry hard to write a typo3 extension.... Try it, learn on it, and become a better Typo3er

Answer (score -1):

There should be a special syntax to name markers for custom fields.

Have a look at this old thread:
http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/extension-modifizieren-neu-erstellen/27095-tt_address-um-link-feld-erweitert-marker-nutzen.html

Where the user was successful with

`###LINK_TX_TTADDRESSEXT_INTLINK###`

So you might try with

`###EMAIL1_TX_TTADDRESSEXT_FIELDTYPE###`

Not sure why the fieldtype and what to put there though!